# In x509, what is the difference between the key-pair and the certificate?

Tags: x509

I've generated a key-pair using `keytool -genkeypair` command. I presume this create a pair of private key and public key.

I've also generated a CSR out of this key-pair using the `keytool -certreg` command. I got it signed by our CA (or whatever they call it) and I got another certificate in return along with it is its thumbprint.

My question is, what am I going to use that certificate for or what is its purpose? I'm still able to generate a JWT just using the private key.

Comment: Certificate is a message, not a key. It carries useful information items.

Comment: I would say that certificate is an ID card of the key pair holder/owner. Public key and information about the owner is included in public certificate.

Comment: The key-pair is for your use only. E.G. a derived certs is signed with the secret key. The certificate holds some info, duration, who and others plus its concerning public key.
A cert is used to sign e.g. a message or a document. Do not forget to send the whole certificate chain for receivers verification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *key* is a set of mathematical parameters describing how to initialize certain algorithms for cryptographic operations, e.g. for signing/verification or for encryption/decryption.

A *key pair* merely is a pair of such *keys* where each key can verify what the other one has signed or where each key can decrypt what the other one has encrypted.

One key in such a pair is declared the public key and the other one the private key. (This choice is not completely arbitrary, there can be different extra requirements to a private key than to a public one.)

There is nothing in these keys declaring that they are bound to a specific person, to a specific issuer, to a specific purpose, to a specific accountability, etc.

This is where X.509 certificates come into the picture: A X.509 certificate is a structure that bundles the public key of a key pair with extra information like the name of the holder of the key pair, the name of an issuer of the certificate, validity time spans, and much more.

This structure furthermore contains a signature of all those other data in the structure. This signature is generated using the private key of the issuer of the certificate.

The information in the certificate in particular allows you to determine the issuer of it. If you trust organization of the issuer to only issue certificates to persons whose identity they checked, and if you successfully validated that the certificate signature is valid and created by the issuer, you can trust the identity of the holder of the key pair of a given certificate.

Thus,

> My question is, what am I going to use that certificate for or what is its purpose? I'm still able to generate a JWT just using the private key.

you provide your certificate publicly to allow people to be sure of your identity when they use the contained public key to validate your signatures or encrypt information they send to you. Without a mechanism like the certificates you'd have to give people your public key in person for them to be sure of that.